# Can I repair broken trust with feral female?

Tags: cats, feral

For the last five years I’ve been feeding and talking to a beautiful little feral dilute tortoise shell female. She was very shy and would run from me and everyone else in the neighborhood but a few months ago she finally asked me to pet her and we’ve been best friends since. The forecast said it would rain for several days and I decided to bring her inside. When she came to my patio for breakfast as she does every morning, I picked her up and brought her indoors. She leapt from my arms and ran outside. Now she runs from me like I’m a stranger again and I am heartbroken. I really need to gain her trust again because her affection is one of the best things in my life. She still comes to the patio twice a day to eat, but instead of letting me pet her she runs away. If she sees me on the street, instead of happily running to me, she runs away. Please advise and thank you in advance. Her name is Bonnie.

Comment: Give it some time and let things happen on her terms, she will come around. We have a former stray that is bonded to me to a point where she acts more like a dog towards me than a cat. Still I am not allowed to pick her up, and she will be wary for the rest of the day after I have to, which is frequent since she needs to see the vet every 4 weeks. Don't force things, let the cat come to you again as you did the first time, and this will fix itself over time.